# how to extract element and text only (filter out attributes, class, in-line css)

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Run this

```
hxs.select('//*[@id="column_one"]/h2/following-sibling::div[1]').extract()
```

And this is example output

```
<div class="OneLinkNoTx">
    <strong>Location:</strong> 
    Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates
</div>
<div class="OneLinkNoTx">
    <strong>Travel Percentage:</strong> 
    None
</div>
<div align="justify">
    Salary: 100k
</div>
```

I want the output to look like this

```
<div>
    <strong>Location:</strong> 
    Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates
</div>
<div>
    <strong>Travel Percentage:</strong> 
    None
</div>
<div>
    Salary: 100k
</div>
```

I just want to have the html element w/o any html attributes. Is it possible with scrapy/xpath ?

Comment: XPath cannot change a document, but you can use it to select all attributes and probably remove them using scrapy. An XPath expression to select all attributes would be `//@*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lxml's Cleaner](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html).

```
In [1]: import lxml.html

In [2]: import lxml.html.clean

In [3]: html = """<div class="OneLinkNoTx">
    <strong>Location:</strong> 
    Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates
</div>
<div class="OneLinkNoTx">
    <strong>Travel Percentage:</strong> 
    None
</div>
<div align="justify">
    Salary: 100k
</div>"""

In [4]: doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

In [5]: clean = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(safe_attrs=frozenset())

In [6]: clean(doc)

In [7]: print lxml.html.tostring(doc)
<div><div>
    <strong>Location:</strong> 
    Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates
</div>
<div>
    <strong>Travel Percentage:</strong> 
    None
</div>
<div>
    Salary: 100k
</div></div>
```

The drawback is that lxml adds a wrapper `div`. To avoid that you can do this:

```
In [28]: elements = lxml.html.fragments_fromstring(html)

In [29]: map(clean, elements)
Out[29]: [None, None, None]

In [30]: print ''.join(map(lxml.html.tostring, elements))
<div>
    <strong>Location:</strong> 
    Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates
</div>
<div>
    <strong>Travel Percentage:</strong> 
    None
</div>
<div>
    Salary: 100k
</div>
```

Notice that `clean` modifies the elements in-place.