# Where does the CSS class "OneLinkNoTx" come from?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is becoming somewhat of a mystery for me. I'm working with a client and found the classname **OneLinkNoTx** in a jsp file.

```
<p class="mute OneLinkNoTx gutter-bottom-quarter hide-on-tablet">
  ...
</p>
```

There are [5,600+ hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=OneLinkNoTx&gws_rd=ssl), [70+ on Gihub](https://github.com/search?q=OneLinkNoTx&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), even a few hits on [Twitter from some Oakley link](https://twitter.com/search?q=onelinknotx&src=typd). So it's not just some random dev class, it belongs to some library for something, but I just cannot figure out what!

Please help!

Comment: *Only you can tell.*

Comment: That’s why I don’t like working with libraries… But apart from that, some class names or IDs could actually come from a browser add-on. Try to disable all browser add-ons and try again, just in case.

Comment: Chrome dev tools allow you to add a "break on attribute modification" that could help you track it down.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435173/how-to-extract-element-and-text-only-filter-out-attributes-class-in-line-css

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as a “CSS class” … :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! It's used in [GlobalLink's OneLink translation product](http://www.translations.com/products/globallink-onelink). From the documentation (not online).

> The advanced integration features of OneLink are implemented by using classes as directives. These simplified classes can be used for clients that are translating into a single language. For multi-language sites, the concepts are the same, so it is important to first understand the single language use details. To use these directives you simply need to define the following four classes in one of your CSS include files:

...

> OneLinkNoTx is used to exclude text from the translation process. This is the most commonly used directive, and many implementations only use this one directive.